# DynamoDB: How to use a filter expression on ios (single column with multiple value)?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services

I am new in Amazon Web Services. I want to apply `expressionAttributeValues filter : value @"3" && :value @"1"`.

How can I do it?

```
AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression *queryExpression = [AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression new];
queryExpression.exclusiveStartKey = self.queryStartKey;
queryExpression.limit = @500;
queryExpression.indexName = @"st-lud-index";

if( addedDate > 0 )
{
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = @"st = :value AND lud > :rangeVal";
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":value":@3,@":rangeVal":[NSNumber numberWithDouble:addedDate]};
}
else
{
    queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = @"st = :value";
    queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = @{@":value":@3};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find instructions on how to do that in the `Perform a Query` section of the following document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html#add-aws-mobile-nosql-database-crud-read

Thanks,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Using keyConditionExpression  you can query with only one value for the partition key at a time. Assuming **st** is your partition key, if you need to get two items one with st=3 and another with st=1, you will need to make two separate requests.

However, **lud** (assuming its your sort key) can use a comparison operator such as <= X or BETWEEN X and Y etc.

Another way to do this is using a scan which will return all items in the table or index. You can use filterExpression to only return those items with st=3 and st=1. Scan is expensive operation so better to call query twice.